# Magento 2 PHP Fatal error during setup:di:compile at 33%

Tags: php, laminas, compile

Currently running Magento 2.4.1-p1. When I run setup:di:compile I've got this output:

```
Interface 'Laminas\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface' not found in /chroot/home/af5d329a/851f14efb2.nxcli.net/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Di/MagentoDiFactory.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 /chroot/home/af5d329a/851f14efb2.nxcli.net/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include()
#1 /chroot/home/af5d329a/851f14efb2.nxcli.net/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/chroot/home/af...')
#2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Magento\\Setup\\D...')
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\\Setup\\D...')
#4 /chroot/home/af5d329a/851f14efb2.nxcli.net/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(134): class_exists('Magento\\Setup\\D...')
#5 /chroot/home/af5d329a/851f14efb2.nxcli.net/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(117): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->includeClass('Magento\\Setup\\D...', '/chroot/home/af...')
#6 /chroot/home/af5d329a/851f14efb2. in /chroot/home/af5d329a/851f14efb2.nxcli.net/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Di/MagentoDiFactory.php on line 17
```

I've looked inside my MagentoDiFactory.php and I have this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Magento\Setup\Di;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Laminas\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

/**
 * Instantiates the type via Magento object manager
 */
class MagentoDiFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        return ObjectManager::getInstance()->get($requestedName);
    }
}
```

So the supposed missing line is there. And now I don't know how to proceed and what to do to resolve this.

Our actual composer.json file is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "require": {
        "php": "~7.3.0||~7.4.0",
        "absolute_design/absolute-slider": "^2.0.0",
        "colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file": "~1.4.1",
        "colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis": "^1.11.0",
        "colinmollenhour/credis": "^1.11.1",
        "colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract": "~1.4.0",
        "composer/composer": "^1.9",
        "doctrine/instantiator": "^1.3.1",
        "ebizmarts/sagepaysuite": "~1.4",
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~7.7.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.3",
        "guzzlehttp/promises": "^1.4",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.8.4",
        "laminas/laminas-captcha": "^2.7.1",
        "laminas/laminas-code": "~3.4.1",
        "laminas/laminas-config": "^2.6.0",
        "laminas/laminas-console": "^2.6.0",
        "laminas/laminas-crypt": "^2.6.0",
        "laminas/laminas-db": "^2.8.2",
        "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": "^1.0",
        "laminas/laminas-di": "^2.6.1",
        "laminas/laminas-eventmanager": "^3.0.0",
        "laminas/laminas-feed": "^2.9.0",
        "laminas/laminas-form": "^2.10.0",
        "laminas/laminas-http": "^2.6.0",
        "laminas/laminas-i18n": "^2.7.3",
        "laminas/laminas-json": "^2.6.1",
        "laminas/laminas-log": "^2.9.1",
        "laminas/laminas-mail": "^2.9.0",
        "laminas/laminas-mime": "^2.5.0",
        "laminas/laminas-modulemanager": "^2.7",
        "laminas/laminas-mvc": "~2.7.0",
        "laminas/laminas-serializer": "^2.7.2",
        "laminas/laminas-server": "^2.6.1",
        "laminas/laminas-servicemanager": "^2.7.8",
        "laminas/laminas-session": "^2.7.3",
        "laminas/laminas-soap": "^2.7.0",
        "laminas/laminas-stdlib": "^3.2.1",
        "laminas/laminas-text": "^2.6.0",
        "laminas/laminas-uri": "^2.5.1",
        "laminas/laminas-validator": "^2.6.0",
        "laminas/laminas-view": "~2.11.2",
        "laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge": "^1.0",
        "magento/composer": "1.6.0",
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~2",
        "magento/magento-composer-installer": "^0.3.0",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.1-p1",
        "magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.2",
        "mageplaza/magento-2-english-united-kingdom-language-pack": "@dev",
        "mageplaza/magento-2-seo-extension": "^2.1",
        "mageplaza/module-ajax-layered-navigation": "^1.0",
        "mageplaza/module-delete-orders": "^1.2",
        "mageplaza/module-gdpr": "^1.2",
        "mageplaza/module-sitemap": "^1.0",
        "monolog/monolog": "^1.17",
        "myclabs/deep-copy": "^1.10.1",
        "nikic/php-parser": "^4.4.0",
        "paragonie/sodium_compat": "^1.6",
        "pelago/emogrifier": "^3.1.0",
        "php-amqplib/php-amqplib": "~2.10.0",
        "phpseclib/mcrypt_compat": "1.0.8",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "2.0.*",
        "phpspec/prophecy": "^1.11.1",
        "phpunit/php-file-iterator": "~3.0.4",
        "phpunit/php-invoker": "^3.1",
        "phpunit/php-text-template": "^2.0.2",
        "phpunit/php-timer": "^3.0",
        "psr/container": "^1.1.2",
        "psr/http-client": "^1.0",
        "ramsey/uuid": "~3.8.0",
        "sebastian/cli-parser": "^1.0",
        "sebastian/code-unit": "^1.0.5",
        "sebastian/comparator": "^4.0.3",
        "sebastian/diff": "^4.0.2",
        "sebastian/environment": "^5.1.2",
        "sebastian/exporter": "^4.0.2",
        "sebastian/object-enumerator": "^4.0.2",
        "sebastian/resource-operations": "^3.0.2",
        "sebastian/type": "^2.2.1",
        "sebastian/version": "^3.0",
        "symfony/console": "~4.4.0",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "~4.4.0",
        "symfony/process": "~4.4.0",
        "tedivm/jshrink": "~1.3.0",
        "th3n3rd/cartesian-product": "^0.3",
        "trustpilot/module-reviews": "^2.6",
        "tubalmartin/cssmin": "4.1.1",
        "webonyx/graphql-php": "^0.13.8",
        "wikimedia/less.php": "~1.8.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
        "bamarni/composer-bin-plugin": "^1.4.1",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.5.0",
        "devster/ubench": "~1.1.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.16.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
        "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
        "phpspec/prophecy-phpunit": "^2.0.1",
        "phpstan/phpstan": ">=0.12.3 <=0.12.23",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "psr/log": "^1.1",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~5.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4",
        "symfony/finder": "^5.2"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "version": "2.3.0",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
        "magento": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com"
        },
        "ebizmarts": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.ebizmarts.com"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am having the issue. How did you fix the error @Ace Optics

Comment: Hi Tora, sadly I don't remember how I resolved the issue. But I would recommend that you update your composer.json according to what is listed on repo packagist, run composer update and try to go through di compile again. PS: Check PHP requirements/compatibilities and all of this stuff before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Please run this in debug and check the call stack to know where MagentoDiFactory is being called from. I have add this issue when migrating from 2.4.1 to 2.4.3 and the problem was that Magento stopped installing laminas modules from default (in my case the log module).

```
composer require laminas/laminas-serializer --no-update
composer require laminas/laminas-log --no-update
composer update
```

you can also check your vendor install folder to make sure the laminas modules are there !

Comment: Hi Joao, thanks for the fast reply, I've run these and now I'm having the error "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages". I have run through this error several times during the upgrade from Magento 2.3.7 to 2.4.1. For some reason, and due to this error, is not allowing me to install the right version of that modules for Magento 2.4.1

Comment: Check your composer.lock file. It should have outdated versions when compared with composer.json. If you have the chance to test this in a DEV environment I would remove the composer.lock file in order to let the composer install the versions that are in composer.json

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the vendor directory and launch

```
composer install
```

to regenerate all the magento standard code